# Why doesn't the keyboard shortcut Insert->Typesetting->Nudge Up work for x\[Prime]?

Tags: formatting

I am using iMac with OS X "El Capitan" and found that Insert->Typesetting->Nudge Up works on "Primed" variables when done from the drop-down menu but not with the keyboard shortcut. The keyboard shortcut I used is control uparrow and I take the uparrow to mean the navigation keys at the lower right of my keyboard which look like small arrowheads.Can anyone shed light on this? 
[image]

Comment: I'm running V10.3 on OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite). I can't reproduce your problem. Ctrl+↑ nudges a `\[Prime]` character upward just fine.